# Blocking the opening of a new chrome window

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to prevent a new google chrome window from opening? Tell me how best to implement this lock. I could not find a suitable extension. Maybe I can just remove this item from the chrome menu and block the keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have just registered on StackOverflow and this is my first answer so I apologise in case I amdoing anything wrong

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-link-in-same-tab-pop/jmphljmgnagblkombahigniilhnbadca?hl=en

Have you tried this extension? I believe it is what you are looking for

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, this question is looking for software/libraries that are against the TOS of this site. So it will be deleted if reviewed.

Comment: Apologies, didn't knew that!